# Many-to-many field vs New Model Django

Tags: python, django, oop, orm

I'm trying to make followers/following functionality and I've thought of two ways. I can't seem to find solution as to which one is the better way.

**Solution 1**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False)
```

**Solution 2**

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="who_follows")
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="who_is_followed")
    follow_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Let me know if there are other ways to go about this problem.

Comment: i think solution 2 is a safer bet. solution 1 would not give you follow time, or something else like the page they were on when the follow happened (suggestion vs search vs mutual

Comment: That is easily achieveable using "through" parameter of ManyToManyField.